# Bind service method to my frontend - Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a service in Angular that has one method in there - say GetName() that returns someones name

I want in my html to be able to do something like {{ $scope.GetName() }} and have this bound to my method result. My main issue is if the name in my service changes (through another controller) then I would like my {{ ..... }} change.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Regards,
Yannis

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind dynamic service calls to a DOM element.

Problably the best way would be to [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) for the name changes within the service, and use a callback function on change. You'd also need a way to notify the controller that the name has changed, so an event listener should also be set up. The listener would call the function that will update the scope variable, say `$scope.nameFromService`. And then in your HTML you'd need only this inside the controller part:

```
{{nameFromService}}
```

Again, to make it clear, this is what happens:

- another controller changes the value in the service
- `$watch` gets triggered and calls a function that (among other things) triggers an event
- the event listener in your controller receives the event and updates the scope variable
- Angular automatically updates the DOM

---

UPDATE

If you can change your service, I'd actually avoid the whole `$watch` thing and just modify the name setter function so it triggers an event when called. That way, all your controllers can be aware of the name changes.

Comment: So use .on and .emit basically? But then I couple my service (that emits) to my controller (that does the on) which isnt really great.

Comment: Not necessarily, your service will emit the message, but it doesn't care who receives it.